# file uploading in asp without ActiveX class

Tags: html, browser, title, head, document-body

Is there a way to check file size on the client (without the use of ActievX which also errors out), before it is passed back to the server? in asp

Answer (score 0):

In ASP? No, by definition. Active **Server** Pages can't do anything before they get a request from the client.

There is a draft [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) that will allow you to perform this sort of check using client side JavaScript. The Mozilla Developer Network has a guide on [getting information about selected files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications#Getting_information_about_selected_files). Once you have a reference to the file, you can just access its `.size` property.

Note that since the specification is a draft, it is rather new and subject to change. This one is very new and thus has [very limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=file api).

You might also be able to achieve what you want using a Java applet or Flash (the latter of which would be better supported).